# I lose keyboard and mouse focus during installation onto VirtualBox?

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, keyboard

I can't do any of the suggested solutions I have found to correct this problem, as I cannot even finish the install.

I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.0.4 on VirtualBox.

Had success once, and have performed the install at least a dozen times in past 36 hours, but once in terminal, I lose focus again.

Can anyone help me sort this out please?

Answer (score 3):

At the bottom right of your Virtualbox window, you have a key specified (Right Ctrl by default I think) calle "Host Key". Here is an example (sorry it is french localized)
[image: Virtualbox return to host key]

This is the key you have to press to exit from Virtualbox window and come back to your host system.

Later when your virtual system will be installed, you will be able to install VirtualBox Guest Additions to have your mouse and your keybord focus automatically and correctly handled between your host and your virtual system.

The host key can be configured in general settings (not settings for your virtual host, but for the whole Virtualbox application)